# Gemfire/gemstone gfsh region cache listener

Tags: gemfire, gemstone

I'm trying to create a region with defined cache listener via gfsh with the following command:

```
gfsh>create region --name=exampleRegion --type=REPLICATE --enable-statistics=true --cache-listener=com.example.RegionChangeListener
```

com.example.RegionChangeListener class is deployed (`>deploy --jar=lib.jar`) within jar but it does not seem to be working - I'm getting:

```
Could not process command due to GemFire error. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException cannot be cast to com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.functions.CliFunctionResult
```

Looks like the class is not being found/recognised - where and how to "register" it so gemfire can initialise it properly?
The class just extends CacheListenerAdapter and implements Declarable.

Answer (score 0):

`>deploy --jar=` is only used to deploy *functions* and not event handlers like listeners, loaders or writers.

Do this instead:

`gfsh>create region --cp=<path to cache listener jar> --name=exampleRegion --type=REPLICATE --enable-statistics=true --cache-listener=com.example.RegionChangeListener`

Comment: I tried that but getting: `Parameter "name" is required. Use "help <command name>" for assistance.
Parameter cp is not applicable for create region` (I have name parameter specified though).

Comment: Let me be more precise.  There is the issue of 1) how you deploy your jar and 2) how you create your region.  Your create region looks fine.  Don't use "deploy --jar=lib.jar" to load your cache listener. Instead, add `--classpath=./lib.jar` to your `gfsh>start server --name=server1 --classpath=./lib.jar ...` command

Comment: Thanks but I still do something wrong here. I have tried `gfsh>start server --name=server1 --classpath=./lib.jar` and even `gfsh>start locator --name=loc1 -- classpath=./lib.jar` before starting the server, and than region creation with my initial command (without --cp) but still getting the same error.

Comment: Your syntax looks great (except for the space between -- and classpath in the locator). The question now is: "in which directory is lib.jar?"  One thing to keep in mind when starting a server using gfsh is that the current directory gets set to your server name. In your case, the current directory is ./server1. So, lib.jar must be inside ./server1. If lib.jar is in ., then your --classpath must be --classpath=../lib.jar.  You don't need the --classpath on the locator since the locator is never used for code execution.

Comment: Thanks. Please ignore space between -- and classpath. I have even tried to add full path to the jar and I can see the path included in classpath after the server is started: `Class-Path: c:\dev\Pivotal_GemFire_821_b18207_Windows\lib\gemfire.jar;c:\dev\my_gemfire\lib.jar;c:\dev\Pivotal_GemFire_821_b18207_Windows\lib\server-dependencies.jar` but getting the same initial error. Tried also to put the lib.jar into the server folder... no change. Hm.

Comment: Since the jar is there and it's on GemFire's classpath, then the problem is no longer the jar. Now we look for other things. Two things come to mind: 1) triple verify that the class is in the jar and the package/class name is com.example.RegionChangeListener.  Second, I don't have a Windows machine on which to test but I suggest you try posting to the users list at: http://geode.apache.org/community/